# Fuzzy Match Query is not considering whitespace

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field called suburb which I need to match on with the following criteria;

- 1 transposition is possible
- 1 change is possible
- The first characters must be correct

Given I there are suburbs that have whitespaces in them I need to treat these more or less as a word and not a phrase.  So if I was to search for

> 'Sheoaks'

Then

> 'She Oaks' should be a match

At the moment, when I perform a Match query on the suburb, using:

- Fuzziness = 1
- operator = AND
- fuzzy_transpositions=true
- max_expansions = 50
- prefix_length = 1

I only get a match when I type in a query where

> 'S?? O??'

- Where 'S' must be correct (desired)
- The ' ' must be present (undesired)
- The 'O' must be correct (undesired)
- And the '?' are allowed to be incorrect (desired)

I want

> 'S?????'

So long as the above limitations are met

Comment: which analyzer has been mapped with the field?

Comment: I am just using the standard analyzer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the intended behavior :

with the `standard analyzer` "she oaks" will generate two tokens : `["she", "oaks"]` and sheoaks only one `["sheoaks"]`.

So your match query try to match `["she", "oaks"]`  vs `["sheoaks"]`. But there is more than 1 transposition from "she" to "sheoaks" and from "oaks" to "sheoaks". So it doesnt match.

you need to use the [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) at [index time and search time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html#analyzer).

to it will generate `["sheoaks"]` at index time and `["she oaks"]` at search time ( from your example ). Then there will be only 1 transposition and it should work.